# How to get the selection which is being dragged in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3 behavior api to implement some drag and drop functionality on my chart. There're some circles on the chart, what I want to do is make the circles able to move around when user is dragging them.

But I don't know how to get the reference of the circle which is being dragged by user. 
In below code, where and how to get the reference of the selection and the current mouse position?

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                .on("dragstart", function(){
                    //do some drag start stuff...
                    console.log('drag start');
                })
                .on("drag", function(){
                    //hey we're dragging, let's update some stuff
                })
                .on("dragend", function(){
                    //we're done, end some stuff
                    console.log('drag end');
                });
```

Somebody please help!

Comment: Look at how these 3 functions are implemented in this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708).

Answer (score 1):

You get the current selection from

```
d3.selection(this)
```

If you want to get the current mouse position, use this code

```
d3.mouse(this)
```

That returns an array, where [0] returns the x position of the mouse, and [1] returns the y position.